How to customize the color of mat checkbox in mat select options
How to customize the color of mat checkboxes in mat select options as seen below
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width:49%">
    <mat-label>Select Group</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="groupNames" name="group" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let group of GroupList" [value]="groupName">
                {{groupName}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

I tried inspecting the elements and styles in browser and there was this class
.mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, .mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    background-color: var(--mat-full-pseudo-checkbox-selected-icon-color);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

that was affecting the background color of the checkbox(which I want to customize) but when same class is over-rided in CSS file in my angular project, the changes are not reflecting

If you are using an earlier version of angular which has some other HTML. Just change the CSS styles to below. Applying the same concepts as the second part of this answer!
.mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: yellow !important;
}


If you want to override the styles inside a component you need to use ::ng-deep (Not Recommended) on the prefix of the class.
::ng-deep .mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: yellow !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo
Since ::ng-deep is Not Recommended, you can use a class to achieve the same thing.
First we specify panelClass to give the dropdown a custom class.
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="toppings"
    multiple
    [panelClass]="'custom-checkbox'"
  >
    @for (topping of toppingList; track topping) {
    <mat-option [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

Then in the global styles, we can add the class.
.custom-checkbox .mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: yellow !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

::ng-deep is not deprecated anymore: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/54219

It's NOT deprecated. ;)

IMHO the term "deprecation" has a special meaning for Angular, due to their deprecation & support practices. They discourage usage of ::ng-deep, but I think this is something different than a deprecation. For me, "deprecated" means that I need to find an alternative ASAP, which is not the case here, it will continue to be supported.

I think "discouraged" or "not recommended" would be better terminology

@NarenMurali The above solution sets the background color to checkbox by default but the checkbox should be unchecked and with the default styles , the custom styles should only be applied when checkbox is checked

@NarenMurali This worked for me: ::ng-deep .custom-checkbox .mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, .mat-pseudo-checkbox-full.mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {     background-color: var(--primary-berlin-blue); } Thanks for the help.

Assuming you are using Angular Material 3, add the following entry to your style.scss file.
<html>
    --mat-full-pseudo-checkbox-selected-icon-color: <your colour>;
</html>

Good luck with your project.
